# How to use dbplyr to store a query in an Oracle temporary table without ever storing the data locally?

Tags: r, oracle, dplyr, roracle, dbplyr

I have a data set that I'm querying which is too large to store on my personal computer. I want to use dbplyr to store the data in a temporary table, but I'm running into problems trying to do this.

Here is my code:

```
library("ROracle")
library("dplyr")

## Let dbplyr know that we're in an Oracle environment
sql_translate_env.OraConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_translate_env.Oracle
sql_select.OraConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_select.Oracle
sql_subquery.OraConnection <- dbplyr:::sql_subquery.Oracle

## Connect to database
drv = dbDriver("Oracle")
host = "myHost"
port = 1521
sid = "myServerName"
connect.string = paste(
  "(DESCRIPTION=",
  "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=", host, ")(PORT=", port, "))",
  "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=", sid, ")))", sep = "")
con = dbConnect(drv, username="myUsername", password="myPassword", dbname=connect.string)

## Create the query
remote = tbl(con, "myTable") %>%
  filter(GRP_ID == 12345)

## Attempt to run the query and store it in a temporary table, but this fails!
compute(remote)
```

This code gives me the following error message:

```
Error in .oci.SendQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
  ORA-14459: missing GLOBAL keyword
```

Has anyone been able to accomplish this task with an Oracle database and dbplyr and, if so, could you please share how you got it to work?

Comment: You know that a entry in an oracle temporary table is only accessible to the session using it. Once the session is closed, the data is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that. My code is creating a report that users can run, so I only need this data set at the time of running it. The whole reason I want to store the data in a temporary table is that I need to mutate a bunch of columns into my dataset that are reliant on some parameters the users will give me when running the report. I only want to mutate the columns one time, so I need to store the mutated data in a temporary table that I can then refer going forward in my code.

Comment: Assuming you have write permission, try using the `DBI` package, specifically `copy_to.src_sql` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the latest version of `dbplyr` automatically recognizes `ROracle` connections and re-routes the it's translations to our Oracle translation, so you don't need to use the workaround at the top of your code any longer after you upgrade.  Also, the `copy_to()` command will be what you can use to cache the results of a query with out the need to download the data.  The `copy_to()` command is smart enough to know when it's being passed a data frame to upload, or a SQL statement it needs to cache.

Comment: Thanks, Edgar. I've seen your name in many threads related to dbplyr and I know you're an expert on this. I gave copy_to() a shot, but now I'm getting error ORA-14459: missing GLOBAL keyword. I feel that this is likely an issue on my end in regards to my user privileges in the database, so I may have hit a deadend. I'm still going to mark yours as the answer, because that is the exact answer to my question. It is really cool that copy_to can handle uploading a local data frame as well as caching SQL queries on the database.

Comment: I am having the same issue. The compute() and copy_to() functions produce the `ORA-14459: missing GLOBAL keyword` error. I am able to use dbWriteTable() to copy data.frames into the database. I haven't been able to use copy_to() for that same purpose. @edgararuiz, the Oracle translations have worked for others? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I filed [an issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/621) for that on the dbplyr repository. Thanks to *mgirlich* who linked a pull request, it should be soon corrected.